# PreDestroy method is not compeleted before container is killed

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, graceful-shutdown

I am trying to achieve graceful shutdown for my spring app which runs on kubernetes. I have defined preDestroy method to perform some cleanup before shutdown but I see that container is removed before preDestroy method completes his execution.

What am I doing wrong actually here ?

Comment: Please link Kubernetes PreStop hook with Spring PreDestroy functionality of application. 
So that container will call the k8s prestop hook before being terminated.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: additionally, if your preDestroy method is already getting called but the pods killed beffore it actually finishes try setting a higher terminationGracePeriod

Comment: during that period can container send request outside of the pod ?